# TSQL - How to output the content of a variable into a table?

Tags: t-sql, variables

As described in the title, I'm looking to store the output of a variable into a "non-variable table". Here is the code:

```
declare @fullpath NVARCHAR(200) = '''Data Source=path\to\folder\'
declare @filename NVARCHAR(50) = 'Country.xlsx'
declare @properties NVARCHAR(50) = ';Extended Properties=Excel 12.0'')'
declare @sheetname NVARCHAR(50) = '...[Country$]'
declare @extraction NVARCHAR(500) =
'SELECT * FROM OPENDATASOURCE(''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'','+ @fullpath+
                                                            @filename+
                                                            @properties+
                                                            @sheetname

EXEC(@extraction)
```

This will output the content of the excel file in table format (country_id and country_name). Now, how would one store this output table in another table? For instance:

```
SELECT * INTO #temp FROM @extraction
```

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

Just use `INSERT INTO` as you normally would. `INSERT INTO` allows for it to be followed by an `EXEC` statement:

```sql
CREATE TABLE #Temp ({Column List});

INSERT INTO #Temp ({Column List})
EXEC sys.sp_executsql @extraction;
```

---

Seems like the OP doesn't know the definition of the files. This, in truth, is a problem, but you can "get around" it. I would therefore `SELECT ... INTO` inside the dynamic statement. You'll need to use a global temporary table, or a user table for this though. I use a global temporary table for this example:

```sql
DECLARE @extraction nvarchar(MAX) =
N'SELECT * INTO ##TEMP FROM OPENDATASOURCE(''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'',' + @fullpath + @filename + @properties + @sheetname;
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;
SELECT *
FROM ##TEMP;
--DROP TABLE ##TEMP;
```

Comment: Already tried... The kicker here is that I want to iterate over a folder containing dozens of files and create a temporary table, each time with DIFFERENT columns. I haven't found a way to make that temporary table "flexible", meaning that it would automatically detect the specific {Column List}. Down the line, I'm looking for full "automation".

Comment: @user14912884  How do you know what the columns are supposed to be?  You could create a dynamic SQL script for this, but you're going to need a sources of useable column names and datatypes for every file.  If you can tells us the specs for that defining data, then we could tell you how to automate it.

Comment: In my head I was looking to exploit the following concept:

SELECT * INTO table FROM OPENDATASOURCE('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Data Source=absolute\path\; Extended Properties=Excel 12.0')...[List1$]

That's neat because you don't need to specify any column (the shape of our data changes often)!

I would use this type of concept in a loop for every file in the folder and only define types and keys post-hoc.

Comment: You can't use `SELECT...INTO` syntax with `EXEC`, @user14912884 ; the table most be well defined *before* you insert the data. Seems like you need to handle the `INTO` inside the dynamic statement.

Comment: Ok, I have just found out you can actually create a table inside a variable, with the possibility to use it outside the scope of the variable! However, if you ever have more elegant solutions, don't hesitate to share. Btw, thank you all for the insights.

Comment: That's what I demonstrate above, @user14912884 , in the latest edit.

Comment: *"Was it?"* Yes, @user14912884  ... Look at the start of the statement in the edit: `N'SELECT * INTO ##TEMP`

Comment: Ah, yes! Indeed =)). I haven't seen it before my eureka moment... Yup, we converged ;) (misscommunication)

Comment: Heh.  Some days you have to work pretty hard for those points.

Comment: Not really, @RBarryYoung . I more often answer questions because they personally interest me. Sometimes due to setting that I feel is an area I'm well versed in, others because it's something I don't get much practice at and so want a chance to. The points often mean little to me.

Comment: @Larnu Agreed, the points don't nearly justify my time either.  Just a little humor because sometimes you have to go the extra mile.